# OneNote without a Signing In?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I have a Microsoft Surface Pro. Pushing the top button on the pen opens up OneNote. Currently I have a LOCAL account on my Surface Pro. I am using a local account rather than a Microsoft account because if I switch to a MS account, it forces me to type in a password every time I switch to this user.

So opening up OneNote with this local account, everytime it asks me to sign in and convert my local account to a MS account. Again, I don't want to do this because of the aforementioned password issue.

So, is there a way to use OneNote on my Surface Pro without having to switch my local account to a MS account?

Yes, I know about `control userpasswords2`, but this is not what I am asking about. That function forces the pc to login to a specific account everytime the pc starts up. This pc however has multiple accounts, and that option precludes the easy understand of some less advanced users on this PC from using their own accounts.

Comment: What OneNote version do you have? Is it paid or free one?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to link your MS account to use the Windows 8 apps. When an app prompts for switching account types, there's a "Sign into each app separately instead (not recommended)" button right there:

[image: image1]

This will bring a dialog where you can simply log into your account without linking it to the PC user:

[image: image2]

Also you won't have to re-enter your password each time you open the app.